# Защита от множественного подключения заголовочного файла

Tags: c++, include, препроцессор

Какой метод лучше использовать:

```
#pragma once
```

или

```
#ifndef XXX_H
#define XXX_H
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

У обоих методов есть свои преимущества и недостатки.

`#define` кроссплатформенный, соответствует стандарту, поддерживается всеми компиляторами, но у него есть очевидный недостаток: если в проекте случайно найдутся *два* header-файла с одинаковым именем, необъяснимые ошибки гарантированы. Особенно неприятно это в случае больших проектов с 3rdparty-кодом. Можно придумать более продвинутую схему, при которой вероятность коллизии уменьшится (например, включать в guard полный путь к файлу в проекте или UUID), но гарантии вам никто не даст. (И вы не сможете потребовать от разработчиков посторонних библиотек следовать вашему стандарту.)

`#pragma once` лишено этих недостатков, потому что теперь ваше намерение прямо сообщается компилятору, а не посредством маломощного препроцесора. Но этот формат поддерживается не всеми компиляторами, поэтому наверняка будут проблемы с портируемостью.

Тем не менее, `#pragma once` поддерживается [большим количеством компиляторов](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability), так что если вы рассчитываете лишь на популярные компиляторы (MSVC, GCC, Clang, Intel compiler) свежих версий, имеет смысл остановиться на этом варианте. Имейте в виду, что многие опытные Unix-разработчики недолюбливают `#pragma once`, так что вам придётся обосновывать свой выбор.

---

Если ваш код есть часть какого-либо проекта, всё становится проще: просто спросите руководителя проекта о том, что рекомендуется к использованию. Выбор между include guard и `#pragma once` — часть coding standards любого проекта.