# Зависимости от библиотеки

Tags: c++, зависимости

Всем Здрасте,
Есть задача: прилинковать С++ библиотеку без лишних зависимостей, то есть:

Есть библиотека **lib1** эта библитека зависит от библиотеки **lib2**.
Есть проект **proj1** и **proj2**.
Они оба зависят от и используют **lib1**.

Но **proj1** *использует* функционал **lib2** соответственно зависимость от этой библиотеки ему *нужна*.
А **proj2** *не использует* функционал **lib2** соответственно зависимость от этой библиотеки ему *не нужна*.

*Как прилинковать **lib1** в **proj2** и исключить зависимости от **lib2**?*

Comment: Для этого используют директивы `#define` `#ifndef` `#endif` во многих стандартных библиотеках они есть.

Comment: в эти директивы нужно оборачивать только #include "awesome.h"?

Comment: По большому счёту если сам awesome.h "защищён" директивами - то без разницы,  но с точки зрения более быстрой сборки, лучше что б всё было между `#ifndef` и `#endif` (тогда компилятор не будет заходить в #include и проверять там #ifndef)

Comment: то есть содержимое файла "awesome.cpp" тоже нужно обернуть в `#ifndef` и `#endif`?

Comment: Да, возможно (зависит от реализации), тут http://cppstudio.com/post/5396/ хорошее описание директив (ваш случай PRODUCT_H).

Comment: Вот есть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/302878/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0

Comment: Тот факт что нужно использовать `#ifdef` и `#endif` я понял, мне не понятно как это все органозовать.

Comment: Никакие директивы препроцессора, типа `#ifdef`, тут никаким боком не помогут. Что за странная идея вообще??? Директивы препроцессора работают на стадии компиляции, а в вопросе идет речь об уже скомпилированных библиотеках. При чем здесь препроцессор? Какое отношение защита от множественного включения заголовков имеет к линковке библиотек???

Comment: О какой платформе вообще идет речь? Какой линкер используется?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Библиотека - это просто архив объектных файлов. В "традиционном" режиме линковка библиотек делается с точностью до индивидуальных объектных файлов. Если при линковке `lib1` в `proj2` удастся аккуратно "выхватить" из `lib1` только те объектные файлы, которые не ссылаются на символы из `lib2`, то линковать `lib2` в `proj2` не понадобится вообще. Задача решена. Для этого обычно нужно, чтобы объектные файлы в `lib1` были продуманно/аккуратно организованы и довольно тонко гранулированы.

Если же какие-то символы из `lib2` все таки притянутся в `proj2`, то ничего не поделаешь: придется либо линковать `lib2` в `proj2`, либо писать "заглушки" для этих символов.

Comment: То есть никакие `ifdef` не помогут выключить ненужный функционал при линковке **lib1** в **proj2** и избежать ненужных зависимостей? Есть ли по этому вопросу какая-то литература? Все мои попытки с `ifdef` окончились неудачей.

Comment: @Space Rabbit: Нет, не помогут. Билиотека уже скомпилирована. Весь функционал в нее уже включен. "Выключить" уже включенный в скомпилированный код функционал нельзя.